# Internet Explore and Jquery Animations

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, animation

I've got a really simple bit of code for making a banner image navigate around when different links are clicked, this works really well in Chrome but not so well in Internet Explorer

I think it has something to do with the `.stop()` IE seems to ignore it and return the background image to it's original position on load.

Does anyone know a work around?

Here's my code:

```
$(function(){

//Begin navigation banner animations

$(".home").click(function(){
    $("#banner").stop().animate({'background-position-x' : '-250px'},3000);

});

$(".releases").click(function(){
    $("#banner").stop().animate({'background-position-x' : '-550px'},3000);

});

$(".events").click(function(){
    $("#banner").stop().animate({'background-position-x' : '0px'},3000);

});

$(".artists").click(function(){
    $("#banner").stop().animate({'background-position-x' : '-1250px'},3000);

});

$(".gallery").click(function(){
    $("#banner").stop().animate({'background-position-x' : '-850px'},3000);

});
```

Comment: can you produce a jsFiddle that can demonstrate the behavior? Also which versions of IE?

Comment: @JamesSeabrook .stop() is working good in IEs, provide more code.

Comment: Did you make it work ? I'm having some troubles with Internet Explorer and .animate() looks awful.

Comment: It was down to different versions of Internet Explorer in the end, older versions seem to allow the animation to run on from where it was last at but newer versions seemed to want to reset the background image to a start point. Usually top left. I changed no code from the above.